# Add borders to multiple excel (.xlsx) sheets in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have multiple dataframes that I put into a list and then export it to excel (.xlsx).

```
library(openxlsx)
     
listas <- list('Banco geral fevereiro' = dados,
               'Gestações duplas ou triplas' = duplas_triplas,
               'Duplicidade do nome da mãe' = dupl_nomae,
               'menos22s mais1500g' = menos22s_mais1500g,
               '22a27s mais2000g' = e22a27s_mais2000g,
               '28a31s mais2700g' = e28a31s_mais2700g,
               'Mês início PN  x n° de consulta' = mes_prenat,
               'n° consultas PN branco ou ign' = pn_ign,
               'Mês de inicio PN em branco ign' = mes_pn_ign,
               'Tipo de parto em branco' = tp_parto,
               'Tipo de gravidez em branco' = tp_grav,
               'Duração da gestação não informa' = sem_gest,
               "Apgar 1 e 5 em branco" = apgar,
               'Escolaridade da mãe n informada' = escmae,
               'Cesarea assistida por enfermeir' = ces_enf,
               'Parto assistido em branco' = parto_ass,
               'Número de filhos > 13' = fil_13)

geral <- openxlsx::write.xlsx(listas , file = str_c( "Críticas de Setembro_", format( now(), format = "%d-%m-%Y" ), ".xlsx" ), na = "" )
```

I put this inside a function. Anyways, I wanted to export the file with multiple sheets like I already do, but I want to center the data in each column and add borders to all rows. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way how we can do it:
With `walk2` function from the `purrr` package we iterate over each dataframe  in listas and

1. Add a new worksheet with the name .x (the name from the list).
2. Write the dataframe .y to the worksheet.
3. Calculate the number of rows in the dataframe.
4. Apply the previously defined `style` to all cells in the dataframe.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2) # diamonds dataset

# style for borders 
style <- createStyle(border = "TopBottomLeftRight", halign = "center", valign = "center")

# fake list
listas <- list(
  'Banco geral fevereiro' = mtcars,
  'Gestações duplas ou triplas' = iris,
  'Duplicidade do nome da mãe' = diamonds
)
# my workbook
my_wb <- createWorkbook()

walk2(names(listas), listas, ~{
  addWorksheet(my_wb, .x)
  writeData(my_wb, .x, .y)
  nr <- nrow(.y)
  addStyle(my_wb, .x, style, rows = 1:nr+1, cols = 1:ncol(.y), gridExpand = TRUE)
})

saveWorkbook(my_wb, "my_file.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there any way I can center and add borders to variables names as well?

Comment: This is the issue of `nrow()`. See `addStyle(my_wb, .x, style, rows = 1:nr+1, cols = 1:ncol(.y), gridExpand = TRUE)`  and change to `addStyle(my_wb, .x, style, rows = 1:nr, cols = 1:ncol(.y), gridExpand = TRUE)` without +1 , but then the last row is not centered. Just play around, this should be manageable!

Comment: Got it working by placing "rows = 0:nr+1". Thank you!